# Allow in-cell editing in compact layout

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, editing, layout

I've added a custom field to my Outlook reading pane.

I can edit that field in single-line layout, but when I switch to compact layout it removes the option of in-cell editing.

[image]

How do I enable in-cell editing with compact layout?

Comment: As is shown in the image, there is no way to select Allow in-cell editing if you choose Compact layout, so this is by design.

Comment: Yes, By default this is not allow, that's why i required other options to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enable in-cell editing in a compact layout, sorry.